# Visual Studio - добавить ссылку на проект

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Мне нужно добавить ссылку на проект.
Действую согласно документации 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f3st0d45(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_1

1. Добавил в решение проект, ссылку на который я хочу указать
2. Нажал Add reference
   В окне Add reference во вкладке Projects появилось имя проекта

В References появляется этот проект. Проект не билдится, т.к. IDE не видит DLL для используемого в коде класса (видимо так). Если сделать AddReference на DLL – всё ок, билдится. 
Что делаю не так? Нужно указать ссылку именно на проект, а не DLL.

Comment: возможно добавленный проект у вас не билдится, возможно у него есть свои зависимости, которые вы не добавили к вашему солюшену. После добавления проекта в солюшн, пробовали этот проект собрать отдельно от солюшена? (правый клик на проекте => Build)

Comment: да, проект сам билдится

Comment: галочку рядом с нужным проектом поставили? Там не достаточно просто выбрать курсором.